# Getting error "Parse error in pattern: length Failed, modules loaded: none"

Tags: haskell, parse-error

```
 --To check the list is in ascending order or not
 ascending::[Int]->Bool
 ascending [] =True
 ascending ((length l) == 1) =True 
 ascending l  =((head l)<=l !! 1) && ascending(tail l)
```

This is my Haskell code and when I try to run this code in my GHCI interpreter I get the following error:

```
  ascending.hs(File_name):4:13: Parse error in pattern: length
  Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Could anyone tell me where the bug is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add a guard. You need to bind the input list to `l` and separate the condition with `|`:

```
ascending :: [Int]->Bool
ascending [] =True
ascending l | ((length l) == 1) =True 
ascending l = ((head l)<=l !! 1) && ascending(tail l)
```

You can replace your use of guards, `head` and `tail` with pattern matching instead:

```
ascending :: [Int]->Bool
ascending [] = True
ascending [_] = True 
ascending (x:y:xs) = (x <= y) && ascending (y:xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not put a conditional in the parameter pattern. A pattern for a list of length 1 would be `hd::[]`.

Comment: No, `(x:[])` or `[x]`. `::` is for type declarations.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I am think SML.